# How to have black-white/gray shade lines in pandas dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have following small dataframe:

```
      A     B    C
O                 
X  12.0  11.0  4.0
Y   9.0  12.0  3.0
Z  16.0  40.0  1.0
Q  23.0  19.0  3.0
R  17.0  15.0  2.0
```

I use following code to plot these data as lines:

```
mydf.plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

And I get following figure:

[image]

However, I want figure in black/white/gray colors. How can I change above code to get this color scheme? Different lines can be shown as of different linestyles.

Comment: `df.plot(color = ['black','white','grey'])` ? but then you need to take care of the background maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot on a given Axes object for which you set a custom [cycler](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html#styling-with-cycler):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(20)).reshape(2,10), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

fix,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(
    cycler(color=[(.8,.8,.8), (.5,.5,.5), (.2,.2,.2)]) *
    cycler(linestyle=['-', '--', '-.'])
    ) #repeats after 9 columns

df.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: I find that with `df.plot`, I can have option `color=['red','blue','green']` and `linestyle='-'` but not `linestyle=['-', '--', '-.']`. Is it possible to have `['-', '--', '-.']` as line style option?

Comment: @mso not that I know of